# Convert database from Antislaed to Drupal

Tags: database, drupal

whether is there a converter database from [AntiSlaed](http://antislaedcms.ru) to Drupal? And if not, how quickly convert the base from Antislaed to Drupal?

Thank you very much. Sorry for bad English and noob-question. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this software uses MySQL or some database that can be converted to MySQL tables then you should be able to use drupal's [Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw) and [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) modules to import your content into drupal.

[This tutorial](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-data-imports-migrate-and-table-wizard) is a good place to get started.